# MySQL Stored Procedure Not Storing

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that checks if a value exist, and if it does not, it will insert it. The problem I am having is it nots stroing. The schema for this procedure is tag_id VARCHAR(24) primary key and tag varchar(255)

Create the Procedure

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `create_tag_not_exist` (IN tag_id VARCHAR(24), IN tag VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags WHERE tag_id = tag_id <= 0 ) THEN
INSERT INTO tags(tag_id, tag) VALUES (tag_id, tag);
END IF;
END //
```

Insert data into it

```
call create_tag_not_exist('abc123', 'doeraeme');
```

Yet the table is still empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the WHERE clause, Tag_id appears to be numeric, but in the INSERT and example call it is VARCHAR(24).   What data type is correct?

Comment: The were clause is reading it as numeric? I'm trying to find if any results with the tag_id exist, so I thought combining count and <=0 would do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE `create_tag_not_exist` (IN tagID VARCHAR(24), 
                                             IN tag VARCHAR(255))
    BEGIN
    IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags WHERE tag_id = TagID)<1) THEN
    INSERT INTO tags(tagID, tag) VALUES (tag_id, tag);
    END IF;
    END //
```

I changed the parameter name from Tag_id to TagID to prevent confusion in the field name and parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would consider prefixing your variables with some string to distinguish them from column names - it will make your query easier to read. I use underscores.

Your IF check is wrong - your bracket is in the wrong place.

```
 IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags where tag_id = _tagid) = 0 THEN
      THEN
         INSERT INTO tags(tag_id, tag) VALUES (_tagid, _tag);
      END IF;
```

I'd also recommend passing in your paramters as the same type as the column you are querying on. Otherwise you will be relying on type conversions (where they exist). So tag_id should really be passed in as an int (assuming it is an int).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things a bit dodgy about your sproc. Try the following:

```
drop table if exists tags;
create table tags
(
tag_id smallint unsigned not null primary key,
name varchar(255) unique not null
)
engine=innodb;

drop procedure if exists insert_tag;

delimiter #

create procedure insert_tag
(
in p_tag_id smallint unsigned,
in p_name varchar(255)
)
proc_main:begin

    if exists (select 1 from tags where tag_id = p_tag_id) then 
       leave proc_main;
    end if;

    insert into tags (tag_id, name) values (p_tag_id, p_name);

end proc_main #

delimiter ;

call insert_tag(1,'tag one');
call insert_tag(2,'tag two');
call insert_tag(1,'tag one');
call insert_tag(3,'tag three');

select * from tags;
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for the complete answer including example, including redefining the parameters to be of a better type and demonstrating the EXISTS keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tag_id` is not NULL, this will always be true:

```
WHERE tag_id = tag_id
```

One solution is to give the parameter a different name from the column:

```
WHERE tag_id = parameter_tag_id
```

Or prefix the column with its table alias:

```
FROM tags WHERE tags.tag_id = tag_id
```